# Problems using Windows Core Audio APIs

Tags: windows, core-audio

I've been trying to get a program working which uses the Windows audio APIs.
The end result will be a programs that checks for volume changes in other audio process. 
I've looked at some of the examples on the Microsoft site and have an undersatanding of what I should be doing.
However when I attempt to implement this I get some errors. I'm starting by trying to get a list, well actually just a count at the minute, of all the audio process running.
The code I'm using is based on the code on the Windows site however I get errors when I try to build it. The two main ones are:

1. 'IAudioSessionManager2' : no GUID has been associated with this object
2. use of undefined type 'IAudioSessionManager2'

There is also a similar one for the 2nd one but relating to IAudioSessionEnumerator.

I'm quite new to C++ programming, more used to Java, so I'm thinking that it's just some silly little mistake to do with header files or something, I've included the .h code and .cpp code below.
If anyone would be able to help me it would be much appreciated.

GetProcess.h

```
#ifndef GETPROCESS_H
#define GETPROCESS_H
#define SAFE_RELEASE(p) { if ( (p) ) { (p)->Release(); (p) = 0; } }

#include<Audiopolicy.h>
#include<Mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 
struct IAudioSessionManager2;
struct IAudioSessionEnumerator;
struct IAudioSessionControl;
struct IMMDevice;
struct IMMDeviceEnumerator;

ref class GetProcess
{
public:
    GetProcess();
};
#endif
```

GetProcess.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "GetProcess.h"
#include<Audiopolicy.h>
#include<Mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>


GetProcess::GetProcess()
{
    IMMDeviceEnumerator* deviceEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDevice* device = NULL;
    IAudioSessionManager2* sessionManager = NULL;
    IAudioSessionEnumerator* sessionEnumerator = NULL;
    IAudioSessionControl* session = NULL;


    int numberOfProcesses = 0;
    int numberOfActiveProcesses = 0;

    AudioSessionState state;

    //create device enumerator
    CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (void**)&deviceEnumerator);
    // get default device
    deviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &device);

    // activate session manager
    device->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioSessionManager2), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&sessionManager);
    //// make enum
    sessionManager->GetSessionEnumerator(&sessionEnumerator);
    sessionEnumerator ->GetCount(&numberOfProcesses);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcesses; i++)
    {
        sessionEnumerator->GetSession(i, &session);
        session->GetState(&state);
        if (state == 1)
        {
            numberOfActiveProcesses++;
        }
        SAFE_RELEASE(session);
    }

    //CLEANUP

    SAFE_RELEASE(deviceEnumerator);
    SAFE_RELEASE(device);
    SAFE_RELEASE(sessionEnumerator);
    SAFE_RELEASE(sessionManager);
}
```

Comment: What version of the Windows SDK are you using?  If you don't know, mention the Visual Studio version.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about which version of the SDK I'm using but I'm using Visual Studio 2008 version 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have version 6.0.  You'll need to download and install [Windows SDK version 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/dlx/en-us/listdetailsview.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b).  IAudioSessionManager2 is only available on Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks Hans, that sorted it.
I knew it would be something silly I did wrong.